# Creating a site programmatically - folder does not exist on server

Tags: development, site-collection, 2013

I'm trying to create a site programmatically using a console application, but have been getting an exception whenever I try to add a new SPWeb `"The folder that would hold URL'/sites/[sitename]' does not exist on the server."`

How do I go about creating this folder? I was under the impression that the `SPWebCollection.Add()` method would create the necessary paths.

The code I'm using is

```
SPSite site;
SPWeb web;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPriviliges(delegate()
{
    site = new SPSite([url]);
    web = site.AllWebs.Add("sites/[sitename]", "title", "description", 1033, "STS#1", false, false);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SPSite site;
SPWeb web;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPriviliges(delegate()
{
    site = new SPSite([url]);
    web = site.AllWebs.Add("sitename", "title", "description", 1033, "STS#1", false, false);
});
```

this should do the trick, just give it the site name and sharepoint will handle the rest :)